# Spring AOP is being invoked unexpectedly

Tags: spring-aop, aspect, pointcut, spring-aspects

I have configured Spring AOP for 2 different packages in our application to log exceptions.
There are 2 different configurations for each package:

```
<aop:config>
    <aop:aspect id="aspectLoggging" ref="abcExceptionAspect">
        <aop:pointcut id="pointCut"
            expression="execution(* com.abc.*.*(..))" />
        <aop:before method="logBefore" pointcut-ref="pointCut" />
        <aop:after-throwing method="logExceptionABC"
            throwing="error" pointcut-ref="pointCut" />
        <aop:after method="logAfter" pointcut-ref="pointCut" />
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>

<aop:config>
    <aop:aspect id="aspectLoggging" ref="xyzlogAspect">
        <aop:pointcut id="pointCut"
            expression="execution(* com.xyz.*.*(..))" />
        <aop:before method="logBefore" pointcut-ref="pointCut" />
        <aop:after method="logAfter" pointcut-ref="pointCut" />
        <aop:after-throwing method="logExceptionXYZ"
            throwing="error" pointcut-ref="pointCut" />
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
```

In a service method call, there are calls to the methods of the classes belonging to each of these packages:

public void method()
{

method1(); -> package abc

method2(); -> package xyz

}

Some exception occurs in method2 which invokes logExceptionXYZ method where we are wrapping it in a generic exception, say ExceptionXYZ, and throwing it further.

But some how after this, the logExceptionABC method also gets invoked and throws a generic exception , say ExceptionABC.

I'm not able to understand as why logExceptionABC method is getting invoked?

Please let me know if someone knows about such an issue!

Regards,
Rahul

Comment: `aop:aspect id` and `aop:pointcut id` are using same IDs.I doubt that could be the problem. You may want to try with unique IDs.

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu - I had noticed the same aop:aspect id's and trying changing it but didn't worked. I missed aop:pointcut id which is also same, the issue is resolved after changing it. Thanks for pointing it out!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same `id` is being assigned to both the `aop:aspect` tags.  Similar is the case with the `aop:pointcut` tags as well.

Try with assigning unique IDs.